# Duplicate Attribute in Entity Framework and Data Annotation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, compiler-errors, .net-framework-version

I have an MVC5 application running on .NET framework 4.7.1 in VS2017.

When I build my application, I am getting below error. Any suggestions as to how to resolve this issue?

> The type 'TableAttribute' exists in both 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

[Attribute error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4f1M.png)

[project references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umTc5.png)

[project references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tyAF.png)

[project references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myL9R.png)

Comment: You should explicitly express which of those TableAttributes you are using by i.e following way : [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Table] or by defining using-clauses correctly.

Comment: @RistoM This is my using classes that I've added.

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

Comment: Perhaps try as @RistoM suggests - [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Table] :)

Comment: @DavidHruška, tried....not working

Comment: Can you put screenshot of the Code line where this error happens? As others have said - the error is that [Table] attribute is defined in more than one Namespaces that are used in the code. And hence its causing some error.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava, I've added screenshot to my question above.

Comment: @pallavi - Can you add screenshot/details of the Project References that you have added (includes nuget)

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava- Hey Prateek, I've added screenshots of my project references in my Question.

Answer (score 3):

Remove "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" from References list
Remove all attribute used by dataannotations like [Key],[StringLength]..
also run

```
PM> update-package -reinstall
```

[image]

[image]